# Unable to locate a class or view for component, livewire - jetstreem

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I had a net project in laravel 8, i just installed jetstream:livewire but when i try to call some compose for example:

```html
<x-jet-dropdown>
```

It throws me the following error that I can't solve
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like it's properly installed. You can always try `php artisan optimize:clear`, or reinstall Jetstream

Answer (score 0):

Seem to be a typo.
In your error message is says jet-dropdowm <- with "m".

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
Any solution?